# jquery ui select menu dropdown not opening

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have 2 jquery ui select menus. Both are initially disabled. Basically one of them is a textbox and it has a prefilled value coming from server. When user clicks 'edit' symbol, that textbox converts to a jquery ui select and based on that value, the other select menu enables. However, that select menu is not opening the dropdown, it just displays that value there. When i try to open that dropdown select menu I get this error in the browser:-
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'index' of undefined
And it points to jquery-ui.min.js and throws a redline on this part of jquery ui js code(just a part of it) :-

```
t.focusIndex=s.index,t.button.attr("aria-activedescendant",t.menuItems.eq(s.index).attr("id"))}}).menu("instance"),this.menu.addClass("ui-corner-bottom").removeClass("ui-corner-all"),this.menuInstance._off(this.menu,"mouseleave"),this.menuInstance._closeOnDocumentClick
```

Unfortunately, when I try to run it in fiddle, the code works fine.

Here is my JS:-

```
var tab_id=0;

    $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
            beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
                ui.jqXHR.fail(function() {
                    ui.panel.html(
                            "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible.");
                });
            },
            activate: function (event, ui) {
                tab_id=ui.newTab.index();
                return true;
            }
        });
    });


    // UI elements initialized state; requires the user to take action to enable editing

    $("#ipVersion_0").selectmenu({
        width:250,
        disabled:true
    });

    $("#ipVersion_1").selectmenu({
        width:250,
        disabled:true
    });

    /*initialize buttons*/
    $("#editFields").button({
        disabled:false
    });

    /*disabling cancel and apply buttons by default*/
    $("#cancelButton").button({
        disabled:true
    });
    $("#applyButton").button({
        disabled:true
    });



    // Enable the editing of IP configuration 
    $(document).on("click","#editFields",function(){

            $("#editFields").button("option","disabled",true);
            $("#applyButton").button("option","disabled",false);
            $("#cancelButton").button("option","disabled",false);


            if(tab_id === 0) {

                /*For 1st tab*/
                var connMode = $("#cfgMethod_0").val();
                if (connMode === 'DHCP') {
                    $("#cfgMethod_0").replaceWith("<select class='ipv4editable' id='cfgMethod_0' name='cfgMethod_0'> <option selected>DHCP</option> <option>static</option></select>");
                    $("#cfgMethod_0").selectmenu({
                        width: 250,
                        disabled: false
                    });
                } else {
                    $("#cfgMethod_0").replaceWith("<select class='ipv4editable' id='cfgMethod_0' name='cfgMethod_0'> <option>DHCP</option> <option selected>static</option></select>");
                    $("#cfgMethod_0").selectmenu({
                        width: 250,
                        disabled: false
                    });
                }

            } else {

                /*For 2nd tab*/
                var connMode = $("#cfgMethod_1").val();

                if (connMode === 'DHCP') {
                    $("#cfgMethod_1").replaceWith("<select class='ipv4editable' id='cfgMethod_1' name='cfgMethod_1'> <option selected>DHCP</option> <option>static</option></select>");
                    $("#cfgMethod_1").selectmenu({
                        width: 250,
                        disabled: false
                    });
                } else {
                    $("#cfgMethod_1").replaceWith("<select class='ipv4editable' id='cfgMethod_1' name='cfgMethod_1'> <option>DHCP</option> <option selected>static</option></select>");
                    $("#cfgMethod_1").selectmenu({
                        width: 250,
                        disabled: false
                    });
                }

            }

        });



    $(document).on("click","#cancelButton",function(){
            $("input[type=text]").prop("disabled",true).css("border-color","");
            $("#editFields").button("enable");
            $("#applyButton").button("disable");
            $("#cancelButton").button("disable");
            if(tab_id === 0){
                $("#cfgMethod_0").replaceWith("<input type='text' id='cfgMethod_0' name='cfgMethod_0' class='ipv4editable' disabled>");
                $("#ipVersion_0").selectmenu("option","disabled",true);
            }
            else{
                $("#cfgMethod_1").replaceWith("<input type='text' id='cfgMethod_1' name='cfgMethod_1' class='ipv4editable' disabled>");
                $("#ipVersion_1").selectmenu("option","disabled",true);
            }
    });

    $(document).on("click","#applyButton",function(){
            $("input[type=text]").prop("disabled",true).css("border-color","");
            $("#editFields").button("enable");
            $("#applyButton").button("disable");
            $("#cancelButton").button("disable");

            if(tab_id === 0){
            $("#cfgMethod_0").replaceWith("<input type='text' name='cfgMethod_0' class='ipv4editable' id='cfgMethod_0' disabled>");
                $("#ipVersion_0").selectmenu("option","disabled",true);
            }else{
            $("#cfgMethod_1").replaceWith("<input type='text' name='cfgMethod_1' class='ipv4editable' id='cfgMethod_1' disabled>");
                $("#ipVersion_1").selectmenu("option","disabled",true);
            }

    });

    $(document).on("selectmenuchange","#cfgMethod_0",function(){
        if($("#cfgMethod_0 :selected").text() === "static") {
           $("#ipVersion_0").selectmenu("option","disabled",false);
            $('.ipv4editable').css("border-color","red");
            $('.ipv4editable').prop("disabled",false);
        }
        else{
            $("#ipVersion_0").selectmenu("option","disabled",true);
            /*disable ipv4 section */
            $('.ipv4editable').css("border-color","");
            $('.ipv4editable').prop("disabled",true);

            $('.ipv6editable').css("border-color","");
            $('.ipv6editable').prop("disabled",true);
        }
    }).trigger('selectmenuchange');

    $(document).on("selectmenuchange","#cfgMethod_1",function(){
        if($("#cfgMethod_1 :selected").text() === "static") {
            $("#ipVersion_1").selectmenu("option","disabled",false);
            $('.ipv4editable').css("border-color","red");
            $('.ipv4editable').prop("disabled",false);
        }
        else{
            $("#ipVersion_1").selectmenu("option","disabled",true);
            /*disable ipv4 section */
            $('.ipv4editable').css("border-color","");
            $('.ipv4editable').prop("disabled",true);

            $('.ipv6editable').css("border-color","");
            $('.ipv6editable').prop("disabled",true);
        }
    }).trigger('selectmenuchange');


   $(document).on("selectmenuchange","#ipVersion_0",function(){
            if($("#ipVersion_0 :selected").text() === "IPv4") {
                $('.ipv4editable').css("border-color","red");
                $('.ipv4editable').prop("disabled",false);

                /*disable ipv6 section */
                $('.ipv6editable').css("border-color","");
                $('.ipv6editable').prop("disabled",true);

            }
            else{
                $('.ipv6editable').css("border-color","red");
                $('.ipv6editable').prop("disabled",false);

                /*disable ipv4 section */
                $('.ipv4editable').css("border-color","");
                $('.ipv4editable').prop("disabled",true);

            }
    }).trigger('selectmenuchange');

   $(document).on("selectmenuchange","#ipVersion_1",function(){
        if($("#ipVersion_1 :selected").text() === "IPv4") {
            $('.ipv4editable').css("border-color","red");
            $('.ipv4editable').prop("disabled",false);

            /*disable ipv6 section */
            $('.ipv6editable').css("border-color","");
            $('.ipv6editable').prop("disabled",true);

        }
        else{
            $('.ipv6editable').css("border-color","red");
            $('.ipv6editable').prop("disabled",false);

            /*disable ipv4 section */
            $('.ipv4editable').css("border-color","");
            $('.ipv4editable').prop("disabled",true);

        }
    }).trigger('selectmenuchange');
```

Here is relevant html snippet:-

```
<form  id="ethernetForm" method="post" action="">
<div id="protocolParIcons">
    <a href="#!" class="sbtooltip" title="Apply"><button id="applyButton" class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-check"></button></a>
    <a href="#!" class="sbtooltip" title="Cancel"><button id="cancelButton" class="ui-icon ui-icon-cancel"></button></a>
    <a href="#!" class="sbtooltip" title="Edit"><button id="editFields" class="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil"></button></a>
</div>

<div id="protocolParMain" align="center">
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#ethernetPortTab1" id="0">Ethernet Port 0</a></li>
            <li><a href="#ethernetPortTab2" id="1">Ethernet Port 1</a></li>
        </ul>

    <div id="ethernetPortTab1">
    <table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <label for="cfgMethod_0">Configuration Method</label>
        <input type="text" class="ipv4editable" name="cfgMethod_0" id="cfgMethod_0" disabled>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
        <label for="ipVersion_0">IP Version</label>
        <select name="ipVersion_0" id="ipVersion_0">
            <option>IPv4</option>
            <option>IPv6</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <label for="ipv4Address_0">IPv4 Address</label>
        <input class="ipv4editable" type="text" name="ipv4Address" id="ipv4Address_0" disabled>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
        <label for="ipv6Address_0">IPv6 Address/Mask</label>
        <input class="ipv6editable" type="text" name="ipv6Address" id="ipv6Address_0" disabled>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <label for="ipv4Mask_0">Subnet Mask v4</label>
        <input class="ipv4editable" type="text" name="ipv4Mask" id="ipv4Mask_0" disabled>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
    <!--
        <label for="ipv6Mask_0">Subnet Mask v6</label>
        <input class="ipv6editable" type="text" name="ipv6Mask" id="ipv6Mask_0" disabled>
    -->
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <label for="ipv4Gateway_0">Gateway v4</label>
        <input class="ipv4editable" type="text" name="ipv4Gateway" id="ipv4Gateway_0" disabled>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
        <label for="ipv6Gateway_0">Gateway v6</label>
        <input class="ipv6editable" type="text" name="ipv6Gateway" id="ipv6Gateway_0" disabled>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Why are your buttons wrapped in an anchor? You're HTML is also missing a number of `</div>` tags too. Testing here: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/kkadhmb3/

Comment: Also not sure why you're defining it as a Text Box and then changing it upon Edit. Why not leave it as Select, but keep it disable until Edit is selected?

Comment: @Twisty : Yes I agree with you but the thing is that this interface is connected to a hardware device that sends me values. The way it has been done is that if I keep it as dropdown , it isnt able to display original value that comes from there. Anyway, but that has nothing to do with this 2nd selectmenu problem. BEcause I even tried enabling it by default but it didnt work. For some reason it does work in fiddle though. Dont worry about missing tags, they are there in my code its just i posted part of the snippet. Unfortunately , it still works in fiddle

Comment: @Twisty : reason for adding a tags is just to have more area around the button for tooltip

Comment: Seems to be working for me. When I change to 'Static' from 'DHCP', the IP select comes alive. I do not see where you envoke `$("#ipVersion_1").selectmenu("open");` anyplace that would cause the menu to open. Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: dont worry about version_1 or anything _1 related tags, they are just there for 2nd tab. It is there in my original code but i didnt post it here since its not relevant . _0 values are for tab 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104339/discussion-between-rajat-bansal-and-twisty).